# The bounded wildcard gives a error using ModelDriven in Struts 2

Tags: java, generics, struts2, model-driven

I'm porting a Struts 1 application to Struts 2.

In the Struts 1 application, there is a `CommonAction` class that inherits from `org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction`.

```java
public class CommonAction extends DispatchAction
```

The `CommonAction` class is also a super class of all the other Action classes in the application like

```
public class ManageProfilesAction extends CommonAction
```

Both the subclasses like `ManageProfilesAction` and the `CommonAction` have action methods that receive requests from the web. In case of `ManageProfilesAction`, the associated form bean is `ManageProfilesForm` while `CommonAction` has form bean named `CommonForm`.

Now using Struts 2 approach, I declared `CommonAction` and `ManageProfilesAction` like

```
public class CommonAction implements ServletRequestAware, ModelDriven<? extends CommonForm> {
  protected CommonForm form = new CommonForm();
  @Override
  public CommonForm getModel() {
    return form;
  }
}

public class ManageProfilesAction extends CommonAction {
  private ManageProfilesForm form = new ManageProfilesForm();
  @Override  
  public ManageProfilesForm getModel() {  
    return form;
  }
}
```

so that both `CommonAction` and its subclasses like `ManageProfilesAction` can have methods that receive web requests along with the associated model/form; `CommonForm` and `ManageProfilesForm` respectively.

However, I'm getting an compiler error:

```
public class CommonAction implements ServletRequestAware, ModelDriven<? extends CommonForm> {
required: class or interface without bounds
found:    ? extends CommonForm
```

Is it somehow workable with some Java generics magic or do I need to change the design thoroughly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use both `CommonForm` and `ManageProfilesForm` as:

```
public class CommonAction implements ServletRequestAware, ModelDriven<CommonForm> {
  protected CommonForm commonForm = new CommonForm();
  @Override
  public CommonForm getModel() {
    return commonForm;
  }
}

public class ManageProfilesAction extends CommonAction {
  private ManageProfilesForm profForm = new ManageProfilesForm();
  @Override  
  public ManageProfilesForm getModel() {  
    return profForm;
  }
}
```

Ofcourse, `ManageProfilesForm` inherits from `CommonForm`.

Answer (score 0):

The interface `ModelDriven` requires a class or interface declaration.

> ```
> public class CommonAction implements >ServletRequestAware, ModelDriven<? extends >CommonForm> {
>
> required: class or interface >without bounds found: ? extends CommonForm
> ```

**You can't use bounded wildcards by implementing an interface.**

The interface `ModelDriven` is a generic interface that takes a *type parameter* which should be a concrete type.

You can read more about this in the [Java tutorial.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)